# SaltStack error: could not cache the WAR file

Tags: salt-stack

Trying to deploy war file using tomcat module in salt.

Getting error as below

[image]

Salt Script

```
tomcat-server:
  archive:
    - extracted
    - name: /opt/
    - source: http://www.us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M1/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1.tar.gz
    - source_hash: md5=e794b1c8a4d1427db42b3cc033e0ba2e
    - archive_format: tar
    - if_missing: /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1/

tomcat_symlink:
  file.symlink:
    - name: /opt/tomcat
    - target: apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1
    - require:
      - archive: tomcat-server

deploy_war:
  tomcat.war_deployed:
    - name: /order-management
    - war: salt://order-management.war
    - require:
      - file: /opt/tomcat
```

Not very sure what seems to be the issue. tried googling around but couldn't get anything concrete

Comment: Could you try running this on the minion with salt-call with debug mode?

`salt-call state.sls install_tomcat_9 -l debug`

And post any errors or stacktraces you see?

Comment: https://github.com/lavnishl/logs/blob/master/ErrorInstallingTomcat.txt ....I could see the following .... [DEBUG   ] Error loading module.tls: ['PyOpenSSL version 0.14 or later must be installed before  this module can be used.']
[DEBUG   ] Error loading module.nacl: libnacl import error, perhaps missing python libnacl package
[DEBUG   ] Error loading module.npm: npm execution module could not be loaded because the npm binary could not be located
[DEBUG   ] Error loading module.ipmi: No module named pyghmi.ipmi

Comment: I saw this : 
Could not find file from saltenv 'development', 'salt://order-management.war' . please check  whether the war file is place under the salt:// folder (refer to your /etc/salt/master,  files_root)

Comment: Thanks that worked , now i am getting error ... missing username and password settings ... (grain/pillar)

Comment: top file location ... /srv/salt/development/top.sls , and /srv/salt/development/states/install_tomcat9.sls and /srv/salt/development/states/tomcatuser.sls .... and entry in top.sls is development: '*': -tomcatuser

Comment: .... entry in tomcatuser.sls .... tomcat-manager: user: user1 passwd: pass1 .... also /tomcat/conf/tomcatusers.xml <role rolename="manager-script"/> <user username="user1" password="pass1" roles="manager-script"/>

Comment: Worked fine now .... Thanks everyone ... mootmoot ... want to accept your ans ... but dont see a way to accept comment as an ans :-/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by mootmoot ... Issue was war file not found ...  I saw this : Could not find file from saltenv 'development', 'salt://order-management.war' . please check whether the war file is place under the salt:// folder (refer to your /etc/salt/master, files_root)